# Get parameter values from .m-file into GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, parameters, matlab-guide

To keep it short, I'm developing a software tool where I would like to import
parameters into GUI from .m-files, but I can't find how to import the parameters.
I'm using `iugetfile` to 'reach it' but how do I insert the parameter values?

If I open the file in MATLAB (command window), then I get the parameters in
the workspace. Is there an easy way to read the parameters into GUI to be able
to use them in functions there?

Answer (score 0):

The way to write data into gui is using set. For example: set(handles.,'String','content'). You can see examples of writing and reading values from here: [(mathworks link)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/gui-with-multiple-axes-guide.html?s_tid=doc_12b)

I would use .mat instead .m if you need to read parameter values.